# An Odd Screen Freeze

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, bios, freeze, nvidia-graphics-card

Approximately three months ago, an update became available for my laptop's *NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650* graphics card. I didn't update it and shut down my computer. When I turned on my computer in the morning, it froze shortly after, not responding to any keyboard commands. The display literally remained as it was. After waiting for a while, I received a blue screen error with the message "***0x0000010E: VIDEO MEMORY MANAGEMENT INTERNAL***," where the initial *HEX* number may vary, and my computer restarted properly. Later, I updated the graphics card, and there was no issue.

I encountered the same problem again almost a month ago. I got the graphics card update through *GeForce Experience* and installed it. I needed to restart the computer for it to take effect. However, just before I could restart it, I closed my browser and was about to restart, my computer froze again. I expected a blue screen error and an automatic restart as previously. I decided to wait. Despite waiting for over an hour, the problem wasn't resolved. I had to shut down the device using the power button. I restarted it, completed the updates, and there was no issue. On command prompt I also carried out `sfc /verifyonly` and received "***Windows Resouce Protection found integrity violations***" message. I ignored it and moved on.

For the third time I got the same issue yesterday. My display was again stuck; the device was unresponsive to any keys except the power button. I pressed it long enough to force-shut down, then my device booted up properly. This time I ran `sfc /scannow`. The result said "***Windows Resouce Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them***".

Regarding that I have a couple of questions:

**1)** Is this problem hardware or software-related? Is there a program or test to detect hardware issues?

**2)** Is it time to update BIOS since my BIOS version is 1.06? I found the latest version, which is 2.06, on the product's official website for my model.

All in all, how can I move on from here? Thanks in advance!

**Device:** *Acer Nitro 5 AN515-55*

**OS:** *Windows 10 Pro Version 22H2 OS build 19045.3324 Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19041.1000.0*

Comment: Merhaba, Usually you can read the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_notes of the various BIOS versions to figure out what they improved and if that matters to you. See acer.com

Comment: The repair abilities of SFC are limited, so if it found problems I would also advise to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). I also note that on my own computer I blocked NVIDIA updates because the new driver caused freezes. You might do the same and go back to an earlier version that didn't have this problem.